# Problem with Android drag - drop UI development

Tags: android, android-layout

I am newbie to android so this might be one of the dumbest question you face.
I am developing UI in Eclipse through drag-drop.I have added many elements in one screen now
the window where you drag-drop UI elements is not growing/scrolling beyond a capacity.
So I am not able to see newly added elements.
Please check image for more details..
[image]

You can observe elements after `Storage Position` are not visible. 
How to check other elements or cant we add elements beyond a certain number/size ?

~Ajinkya.

Comment: But I believe that the best way to design layouts is to manually code the layouts using XML file. It is not as much as difficult.

Comment: @Andro:This is my first app , will try manual coding once I get some hands on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many elements as you want. I can see a bunch of LinerLayouts for each of your items, but each linear layout is one row and has a horizontal orientation, correct? I'm not sure what you have as your overlying view, but make sure that all of those items are inside of a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. You can wrap that in a `<ScrollView>` to add a scrollbar to it. Here is a [Scrollview example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example)

Side note: Also, the drag and drop is nice to look at, but I've always had a better experience directly editing the xml, even if I started creating the layout with the GUI. It's easier to tell what is going on with each element and make changes. It's best to check the way everything looks in the emulator too, sometimes it can look different than in the GUI editor, especially if items are put into your interface programmatically.

Comment: @TomHarrigan: Thanks,will try once I get into it.The problem with drag and drop is the place where you drag elements is restricted so I cann't see newly added elements.In image you can see elements afer `Storage Position` are not visible.

Comment: Understood, take a look at the scrollview example, it should does a pretty good job showing you exactly what to do.

Comment: I have added `scrollview` as a parent element.Its working fine on emulator,I can see the scrollbar.Problem is with eclipse drag-drop development space.

Comment: You've exceeded the capabilities of the drag and drop interface. If you really want a work-around, comment out the sections that are completed to see the lower ones as you create them in the drag and drop and then when you're all done un-comment the higher sections. Good luck.

Comment: @TomHarrigan: Thanks. It looks like the question was pretty confusing :) Will try to keep it simple now onwards.